# Деление массива двумерного на строку в Питон

Tags: python

Как в Питоне происходит деление двумерного массива на строку? Пробовал вычитать строку - результат будет тоже двумерным массивом.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Numpy

Comment: Пример вашей программы приведите. С входными данными и ожидаемым результатом.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, в Питоне в библиотеке NumPy уже предусмотрена комбинация - если двумерный массив на строку, то результатом будут строки исходного массива, деленные на эту `строку`.
Было: